# Cannot Access Attach Method using SwiftMailer in Symfony 1.4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-1.4, swiftmailer

I'm trying to attach a file using SwiftMailer, but when I call the `->attach()` method I get: method attach not found in swift_mime_message

Currently, the message sends, but it has no attachment.

Controller code below:

```
$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 587, 'ssl')
    ->setUsername('project@notworking.com')
    ->setPassword('Work_Pls')
;

// Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

$html = $this->getPartial("email/confirmation", $model);
$subject = "Order Confirmation";

// Create the message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance();

// Give the message a subject
$message->setSubject($subject);

// Set the From address with an associative array
$message->setFrom(array('admin@derp.com' => 'Portal Noreply'));

// Set the To addresses with an associative array
$message->setTo(array('derp@gmail.com'));

// Give it a body
$message->setBody($html);

// Optionally add any attachments
$message->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath('uploads/important.jpg'));

// Send the message
$mailer->send($message);
```

Comment: Is that the exact message, method attach not found? Not anything about not found on non-object or etc? Just need to be sure sorry :p

Comment: "method attach not found in swift_mime_message" is the exact message I'm getting

Comment: I also see that `->attach()` is not present in the Swift_Mime_Message interface. Not sure why, or what to do next.

Comment: Can you `var_dump($message);` after the `newInstance` line, and before the attach line and provide the output. I find it odd that you theoretically get an instance of `Swift_Message`, but at `attach`, you have a `Swift_Mime_Message` object.

Comment: Thanks for these comments. Although I used a different method they helped me work through this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using a different mailing method. I put mailing parameters in factories.yml, which looks like this:

```
mailer:
  class: sfMailer
  param:
    logging:           %SF_LOGGING_ENABLED%
    charset:           %SF_CHARSET%
    transport:
      class: Swift_SmtpTransport
      param:
        host:       smtp.gmail.com
        port:       587
        encryption: tls
        username:   goober@gmail.com
        password:   derpderp
```

Then I changed my controller to this:

```
// Send email
$html = $this->getPartial("email/order_confirmation", $model);
$subject = "Order Confirmation";
$to = $derp->getUser()->getEmail();

$message = $this->getMailer()->compose(
    array('admin@derp.com' => 'Portal Noreply'),
    $to, $subject);
$message->setBody($html, 'text/html');
$message->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath('/projects/derp.jpg'));
 $sent_count = $this->getMailer()->send($message);
```